# how to order each df in a list automatically

Tags: r

I  have a list of df lst1 and a df for sorting the dfs in lst1. It is possible to write a code to sort lst automatically with df setup instead of sorting it one by one manually? Any suggestion? wiht `map`? The df in lst need to be order by Var1 and then Var2 if it is not NA.

[image]

df:
[image]

```
lst<-list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("1953-07-07", 
"1963-07-02", "1940-09-11", "1955-12-31", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("2016-03-14", 
"2017-04-04", NA, "2016-05-02", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c(NA, 
NA, "UN-UNK-2015", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), Visit = c("Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"
), VISND = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

structure(list(File = c("Demographics", "DiseaseStatus", "Visits"
), Var1 = c("SubjectID", "SubjectID", "Visit"), Var2 = c(NA, 
"DSDT", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmap` to loop over the rows of 'df', extract the `lst` element with `[[` based on the first column, and use `across` within `arrange` on the other column values

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst2 <- pmap(df, ~ {
          nm1 <- ..1
          nm2 <- as.vector(na.omit(c(...)[-1]))
         lst[[nm1]] %>%
           arrange(across(all_of(nm2)))
     })
names(lst2) <- names(lst)
```

---

If there are cases where we don't need to do any `arrange`, i.e. the columns of df except the first one are NA, then use a condition with `if/else`

```
pmap(df, ~ {
          nm1 <- ..1
          nm2 <- as.vector(na.omit(c(...)[-1]))
      if(length(nm2) > 0) {
         lst[[nm1]] %>%
           arrange(across(any_of(nm2)))} else lst[[nm1]]
     })
```

Comment: what if `df<- structure(list(File = c("Demographics", "DiseaseStatus", "Visits"
), Var1 = c(NA, "SubjectID", "Visit"), Var2 = c(NA, 
"DSDT", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))`

Comment: Could you explain a little more on `c(...)`? Many thanks

Comment: @Stataq the `...` implies all the element  from that particular row.  with `c(`, we are concatenating it to a `vector`.  if you use `list(...)`, those element will be a `list`.  When we say `..1`, it represents the first element i..e 'File',column. which we use for extracting the `list` element.  The other ones `[-1]`, are used for in `arrange`

Comment: Thanks. I have an similar question that involved one more step of grouping, I post the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68275901/how-to-group-and-then-order-each-df-in-a-list .

Comment: @Stataq I posted a solution there. please check if that is what you intended

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234586/discussion-between-stataq-and-akrun).