# how to group and then order each df in a list

Tags: r

I  have a list of df lst1 and a df for sorting the dfs in lst1. It is possible to write a code to sort lst automatically with df setup instead of sorting it one by one manually? Any suggestion? wiht `map`? The df in lst need to be grouped by Var1 and then ordered by Var2 if it is not NA.

[image]

df:

[image]

```
lst<-list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("1953-07-07", 
"1963-07-02", "1940-09-11", "1955-12-31", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("2016-03-14", 
"2017-04-04", NA, "2016-05-02", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c(NA, 
NA, "UN-UNK-2015", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("101-01-101", 
"101-02-102", "101-03-103", "101-04-104", "104-05-201"), Visit = c("Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", 
"Screening: -28 Days to Day 1", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"
), VISND = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

df <-structure(list(File = c("Demographics", "DiseaseStatus", "Visits"
), Var1 = c("SubjectID", "SubjectID", NA ), Var2 = c(NA, 
"DSDT", "Visit")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `arrange` and then do the `group_by`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst2 <- pmap(df, ~ {
          nm1 <- ..1
          nm2 <- as.vector(na.omit(c(...)[-1]))
      if(length(nm2) > 0) {
         lst[[nm1]] %>%
           arrange(across(any_of(nm2))) %>%
           group_by(across(any_of(nm2))) 
           } else lst[[nm1]]
     })
names(lst2) <- df$File
```

Comment: will grouped then order has the same results as ordered and then grouped?

Comment: @Stataq In the current data, the inputs are all ordered, so additional ordering didn't make any changes.  But, suppose you want to maintain the same order in other calculations, you can convert to `factor` with `levels` specified i.e. after the `arrange` step, do `group_by(across(any_of(nm2), ~ factor(., levels = unique(.))))`